# Add check constraint to a stored procedure

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, stored-procedures, constraints

I'm a noob, I want to add this check contraint to a stored procedure, I don't know if it possible to do this if is possible  or a table too

```
IF EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM PRESTAMO_SALA PS
  WHERE PS.START_TIME <= @END_TIME 
      AND PS.END_TIME >= @START_TIME 
      AND PS.[DATE] = @DATE
      AND PS.ID_SALA = @ID_SALA 
      )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question but you can definitely use `if exists` in a stored procedure.

```
IF EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM PRESTAMO_SALA PS
  WHERE PS.START_TIME <= @END_TIME 
      AND PS.END_TIME >= @START_TIME 
      AND PS.[DATE] = @DATE
      AND PS.ID_SALA = @ID_SALA 
      )

--DO SOME STUFF

ELSE
--DO SOMETHING ELSE
```